# How do you show date only and NOT time using date filter in twig

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to output only date like the following:

```
collection_item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_date.value|date()
```

But the output contains both date and time: `September 22, 2016 00:00`

I want only the date part (`September 22, 2016`), without the time (`00:00`).

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html):

> The format specifier is the same as supported by [`date`](http://www.php.net/date), except when the
>   filtered data is of type `DateInterval`, when the format must conform to
>   `DateInterval::format` instead.

So you should simply pass a format string. For example:

```
collection_item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_date.value|date('F n, Y')
```

Comment: Sidenote : `null` will be converted to the current date/time